# Visual Studio GridView in Web form: How to insert column with radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, gridview

This is homework, a Web site to rate doctors.  In my GridView, I want a column with rows of five radio buttons, so that each doctor can be rated.  How do I get the radio buttons?  When I dragged a Radio Button List from the Toolbox, it didn't show up in Design mode.

Here is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewDoctor" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceDoctor" DataKeyNames="DoctorPicture" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="DoctorPicture" HeaderText="DoctorPicture">
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorName" HeaderText="DoctorName" SortExpression="DoctorName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorSpecialty" HeaderText="DoctorSpecialty" SortExpression="DoctorSpecialty" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate Now">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="fave" HeaderText="fave" SortExpression="fave" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add asp:RadioButton instead of RadioButtonList.  Specify GroupName on each RadioButton so they work together.  Something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewDoctor" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceDoctor" DataKeyNames="DoctorPicture" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="DoctorPicture" HeaderText="DoctorPicture"</asp:ImageField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorName" HeaderText="DoctorName" SortExpression="DoctorName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorSpecialty" HeaderText="DoctorSpecialty" SortExpression="DoctorSpecialty" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate Now">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="Group1"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="Group1"></asp:RadioButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="fave" HeaderText="fave" SortExpression="fave" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It worked!  Now I need to see how to grab what the user selects and store it in Session.